# How to register soft-navigation changes in mPulse Boomerang for an Angular app?

Tags: angular, akamai, boomerang, rum

The `BOOMR.plugins.Angular` [plugin](https://developer.akamai.com/tools/boomerang/legacy-spa#angularjs) seems to be used for `AngularJS 1.x` and so far I failed to find a `Angular` example or plugin I could use. Based on the docs I came up with the following solution:

```js
@Injectable()
export class BoomerangBootstrapService implements OnAppInit {
    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    onAppInit() {
        const boomr = window['BOOMR'];
        const callbacks = {};

        this.router.events.subscribe((e) => {
            if (!boomr) {
                return;
            }
            if (e instanceof NavigationStart) {
                boomr.plugins.SPA.last_location(e.url);
                const callback = () => {
                    boomr.plugins.SPA.markNavigationComplete();
                };
                callbacks[e.url] = callback;
                boomr.plugins.SPA.route_change(callback, []);
            } else if (e instanceof NavigationEnd || e instanceof NavigationCancel || e instanceof NavigationError) {
                const callback = callbacks[e.url];
                if (callback) {
                    callback();
                    delete callbacks[e.url];
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I insert a helper `diagnostics script` using the browser console to debug the calls I can see that the registration is correct but I don't see any data being submitted on navigation.

**diagnostics script:**

```js
(function(spa) {
  'use strict';
  var rc = spa.route_change;
  var ll = spa.last_location;
  var cm = spa.markNavigationComplete;

  spa.last_location = function(url) {
    console.log('last route url was ' + url);
    ll(url);
  };

  spa.route_change = function(c, o) {
    console.log('route_change start');
    rc(c, o);
  };

  spa.markNavigationComplete = function() {
    console.log('route_change completed');
    cm();
  };
})(window.BOOMR.plugins.SPA);
```

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to create a [custom plugin](https://akamai.github.io/boomerang/tutorial-creating-plugins.html) or call additional methods? Could you point me to a working code example or plugin git project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need now to instrument anything in your Angular app. From Boomerang version 1.632 all SPAs are supported with simply checking the

[Enable Single Page App (SPA) monitoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAPt0.png)

Docs available here

https://developer.akamai.com/tools/boomerang/?language=en_US?language=en_US#single-page-apps